# i am getting a error Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Good Afternoon all for some reason i am getting a error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement,
i have checked all the %s and they all show as 7 as well as all the items in the sql, i am sure is not much but if someone could take a look that would be great

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="*****",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()


airline_spans = resp.html.find('.SearchResultFlightListRow')
print (airline_spans)
airline_list = [span.text.split('\n') for span in airline_spans]

for flight in airline_list:
    if len(flight) == 7:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate, status = flight
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} and flight status is {status}')

    elif len(flight) == 6:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate = flight
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} ')

    elif len(flight) == 5:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated = flight
        gate = 'IDEL'
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'

print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate ')


sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (origin, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

val = (From, to, flightno, scheduled, estimated, status, gate)
#data.append(val)


# doing a batch insert
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
```

Comment: `executemany` expects a list of tuples, but you’re only giving it a tuple for *one* execution. I don’t think you want to execute *many*, do you?

Comment: im not sure mate still a n00b at this :) all i want to be able to do is put the data in the database :)

Comment: Try changing `executemany` to `execute`...

Comment: ok kinda worked but it only inserted one row when i wanted all the rows